# better solution than a switch for change classNames

Tags: javascript

I have created a clock, that connected to date().getHours / minutes /Seconds
The images that are shows are embedded in different classes.

Now when i want to change the images i wrote a switch for every second minute and hours..
Thats probably more code than googles engine. So i wonder if there is a more simple solution.

This is some code of the hour switch
so when minute 15 gets to the clock it change the className to one and five.

```
switch(h){

        case 15:
            x = hours.appendChild(hour1).className = "clock-digit-one";
            x = hours.appendChild(hour2).className = "clock-digit-five";
            break
        case 16:
            x = hours.appendChild(hour1).className = "clock-digit-one";
            x = hours.appendChild(hour2).className = "clock-digit-six";
            break

        default:
            x = hours.appendChild(hour1).className = "clock-digit-zero";
            x = hours.appendChild(hour2).className = "clock-digit-zero";

    }
```

I have created a jsFiddle  that shows more of the code.
Any tips would be great. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Xk49c/2/

Thanks

Comment: I would take the time, convert to an array "t" with 6 positions (h,h,m,m,s,s) then reference a digits array["zero","one..."nine"] and then use hours.appendChild(hour1).className = "clock-digit-" + digit[t[0]];hours.appendChild(hour2).className = "clock-digit-" + digit[t[1]]; etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just expanding my initial comment

```
  var digits = new Array("zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine");
  var h=new Date().getHours().toString();
  var m = new Date().getMinutes().toString();
  var s = new Date().getSeconds().toString();
  var t = ((h>9?h:"0"+h)+ (m>9?m:"0"+m) +(s>9?s:"0"+s));

  hours.appendChild(hour1).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(0,0+1)];
  hours.appendChild(hour2).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(1,1+1)];
  minutes.appendChild(minute1).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(2,2+1)];
  minutes.appendChild(minute2).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(3,3+1)];
  seconds.appendChild(second1).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(4,4+1)];
  seconds.appendChild(second2).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[t.substring(5,5+1)];
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Create an array of human-readable numbers:

```
var digits = ["zero", "one", "two", ..., "nine"];
```

Break down `h` into first and second digit:

```
var hours = Math.floor(h / 10);
var minutes = h % 10;
```

Index into `digits` to determine the class name you should be using:

```
hours.appendChild(hour1).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[hours];
hours.appendChild(hour2).className = "clock-digit-" + digits[minutes];
```

Comment: There can be numbers in class names, so why use human readable number forms?

Comment: @TomášZato: Because that's what the OP already does, and it's so extremely easy to do?

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is a simpler solution. For example, you can make class names such as `clock-digit-[number]` and then use string concatnation to make the className:

```
x = hours.appendChild(hour1).className = "clock-digit-"+h;
```

To find out form which digits the time number consists, you can convert the number to string and `.split()` it. This is not the most effective way, but its simple and clear.

```
var numbers = h.toString().split("");   //Will give ["1","5"] for 15
```

Then you add numbers to your div using `for` loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {   //We loop through ["1","5"]
  var num = document.createElement("div");     //Use your element type here!
  num.className = "clock-digit-"+numbers[i];   //Get either 1 or 5
  hours.appendChild(num);
}
```

In case you wanted to use the original class names, you can create an Array, like @Jon proposed:

```
var digits = ["zero", "one", "two", ..., "nine"];
```

Then, the `for` loop would look like that:

```
for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {   //We loop through ["1","5"]
  var num = document.createElement("div");     //Use your element type here!
  num.className = "clock-digit-"+digits[numbers[i]];   //Get either 1 or 5
  hours.appendChild(num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a solution that keeps an associative array of digits to their associated classes.  Then you only need two lines to set each digit (instead of every single combination of two digits individually)

Something along these lines:

```
var digitToClass = {
    0: 'clock-digit-zero',
    1: 'clock-digit-one',
    2: 'clock-digit-two',
    3: 'clock-digit-three'
    //..
};

var minute = "03";

minutes1.className = digitToClass[minute[0]];
minutes2.className = digitToClass[minute[1]];
```

Comment: That would still result un very long code, which is what we do not want, do we?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the class names and refer to its index (60 items), that's better than a switch.

EDIT: Others have posted examples and better solutions, but the logic is that an array is the best solution.